# SQL a meaninful column in execution but is not saved

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my ASP website, I have a select query goes like this:

```
select [china] from [countries]
```

China is a column in the table countries with value hongkong, I want during execution an extra column value to appear but is not saved in the table just appear during execution to give a meaningful meaning for the user to see:

ex:

What should appear:

```
china: Honkong
street: first
```

Street is the column name with value of first, How to add this into a select statement during execution ??

You know how we can change the column name during execution ex.(select china AS eastasia from countries) but instead a whole column!!

please somebody help me in this problem

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because the syntax appears to be SQL Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT china, 'first' AS street FROM countries`

Comment: Thanks that Worked!!, at first it didnt work because my select statement had UNION of other selects, and I added to one statement and then after I added to other statements IT WORKED!! Thnks!!